# Inline action with no object instance in Django Admin

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am having troubles with working with *GenericTabularInline* in my django app.

The case is:

- I have some object called Status which has relation to some Property
  (ForeignKey). I would like to have an additional actions on that
  Status object in Property change form.
- I am using inline_actions library to create custom actions for
  Status object.
- The struggle is when I try to render that Inline instance if there
  is no Status object attached to my Property.

Is there any way I can override my custom actions to render even if there is no Status object attached to my Property?

Here is my Inline code:

```
class AbstractPropertyCheckInline(InlineActionsMixin, GenericTabularInline):

    model = Status
    readonly_fields = ('status_type', 'last_check', 'additional_message')
    extra = 0
    inline_actions = ['revalidate']

    def revalidate(self, request, obj, parent_obj=None):
      # My revalidation code
```

What *revalidate* does is that it creates a Status object and attaches it to the Property if such doesn't exist. I would like to trigger such behavior from within admin page

Comment: how about `extra = 1`?

Comment: I though about it but when I try to save it, it is somehow not saved

Comment: The thing is that the inline actions are supposed to work on the inline instances (the related objects, i.e. `Status`) whereas you're actually running an action on the parent object (`Property`). I think you should consider adding the action on `Property` instead of using inline actions for this specific purpose.

Comment: The case why I am doing that on Property inline action is that I would like to show some additional info about that Status which is connected to certain Property object.

So basicly: I want to show info about Property and then additional information about it's Status.

Comment: And why can't that be done using separate actions? The action to create a related status if the property does not have a status should be an action on property. The action of showing additional info of the (existing) status should be an inline.

Comment: Well.. that's actually a very good idea! I didn't understand you the first time, but I did that and it's working quite well :) Please post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline actions are supposed to work on the inline instances (the related objects, i.e. `Status` in your case) whereas you're actually trying to run an action on the parent object (`Property`).

So you should probably think which part of the action pertains to the `Property` and which part to each `Status` instance.

Then separate your actions: One on `Property` to create a new `Status` instance if it doesn't have any and one inline action for each of your `Status` inline instances to do additional stuff on each child.